# windows equivalent to touch

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, script, touch

Is there a Windows equivalent to the `touch` command?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser . While it's [OK - and encouraged - to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.207180051.1051913068.1684039935-1108829733.1673436791), this site is a Q&A style site, so it'd be best to edit the question to put the situation/dilemma/question/problem there, and then put the solution as an answer.

Comment: While you're at it, maybe give a couple of examples in the answer so people will know what format the timestamp uses. Or let people know if the timestamp format depends on your system settings.

Answer (score 2):

### touch.ps1

> **Usage: touch [FILE]...**

---

```
   param(
        [Parameter()]
        [String]$file
    )
    if(Test-Path -Path $file){
        (Get-Item -Path $file) | % {$_.LastWriteTime = (Get-Date)}
    }
    else{
        (New-Item $file)
    }
```

---

Add the directory to your touch.ps1 script to the PATH environment variable and you should be set.